# Why does DBUnit fail to export full dataset from MySQL with a DatabaseUnitRuntimeException?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, dbunit

I am trying to start using DBUnit in order to test my DAO layer in my Java webapp.

The first thing I want to do is to generate a full export from my dev database into an XML dataset, so I can use it to populate an in-memory DB to be used in the tests.

I followed [the example on DBUnit's website](http://dbunit.sourceforge.net/faq.html#extract), but it fails and results in an empty XML file.

The export for one table works fine.

Here is the code to do the export :

```
public class DBUnitDatasetExtractor {

    public static final String DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    public static final String JDBC_URL = "jdbc:mysql://192.168.56.4:3306/myschema";
    public static final String SCHEMA = "myschema";
    public static final String USER = "myuser";
    public static final String PASSWORD = "password";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        Logger root = (Logger) LoggerFactory.getLogger(Logger.ROOT_LOGGER_NAME);
        root.setLevel(Level.DEBUG);

        // database connection
        Class driverClass = Class.forName(DRIVER);
        Connection jdbcConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(JDBC_URL, USER, PASSWORD);
        IDatabaseConnection connection = new DatabaseConnection(jdbcConnection, SCHEMA);

        // partial database export - works
        QueryDataSet partialDataSet = new QueryDataSet(connection);
        partialDataSet.addTable("desk");
        FlatXmlDataSet.write(partialDataSet, new FileOutputStream("partial.xml"));

        // full database export - does not work
        IDataSet fullDataSet = connection.createDataSet();
        FlatXmlDataSet.write(fullDataSet, new FileOutputStream("full.xml"));
    }

}
```

What am I doing wrong ?

I set the logger level to debug, so here is the relevant trace :

```
16:41:34.551 [main] DEBUG o.d.database.DatabaseTableMetaData - getColumns() - start
16:41:35.548 [main] DEBUG org.dbunit.util.SQLHelper - isEscaped returns 'false' for tableName=desk (dbIdentifierQuoteString=`)
16:41:35.549 [main] DEBUG org.dbunit.util.SQLHelper - Database does not store upperCase or lowerCase identifiers. Will not correct case of the table names.
16:41:35.549 [main] DEBUG o.d.database.DatabaseTableMetaData - Validating if table 'desk' exists in schema 'tango' ...
16:41:35.550 [main] DEBUG org.dbunit.util.SQLHelper - close(resultSet=com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC42ResultSet@28eaa59a) - start
16:41:35.550 [main] DEBUG o.dbunit.dataset.OrderedTableNameMap - update(tableName=desk, object=table=desk, cols=[], pk=[]) - start
16:41:36.552 [main] DEBUG o.dbunit.dataset.OrderedTableNameMap - getTableName(tableName=desk) - start
16:41:36.552 [main] DEBUG o.dbunit.dataset.OrderedTableNameMap - getTableName(tableName=desk) - end - result=DESK
16:41:36.552 [main] DEBUG o.dbunit.dataset.OrderedTableNameMap - getTableName(tableName=desk) - start
16:41:36.552 [main] DEBUG o.dbunit.dataset.OrderedTableNameMap - getTableName(tableName=desk) - end - result=DESK
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:59104', transport: 'socket'
Exception in thread "main" org.dbunit.DatabaseUnitRuntimeException: At least one column is required to build a valid select statement. Cannot load data for table=desk, cols=[], pk=[]
    at org.dbunit.database.DatabaseDataSet.getSelectStatement(DatabaseDataSet.java:127)
    at org.dbunit.database.AbstractResultSetTable.getSelectStatement(AbstractResultSetTable.java:134)
    at org.dbunit.database.AbstractResultSetTable.<init>(AbstractResultSetTable.java:105)
    at org.dbunit.database.ForwardOnlyResultSetTable.<init>(ForwardOnlyResultSetTable.java:59)
    at org.dbunit.database.CachedResultSetTableFactory.createTable(CachedResultSetTableFactory.java:60)
    at org.dbunit.database.DatabaseDataSet.getTable(DatabaseDataSet.java:319)
    at org.dbunit.database.DatabaseTableIterator.getTable(DatabaseTableIterator.java:89)
    at org.dbunit.dataset.stream.DataSetProducerAdapter.produce(DataSetProducerAdapter.java:83)
    at org.dbunit.dataset.xml.FlatXmlWriter.write(FlatXmlWriter.java:124)
    at org.dbunit.dataset.xml.FlatXmlDataSet.write(FlatXmlDataSet.java:378)
    at ch.unine.tango.persistence.DBUnitDatasetExtractor.main(DBUnitDatasetExtractor.java:46)
```

Here is the database info :

```
17:02:28.007 [main] DEBUG o.dbunit.database.DatabaseConnection - Database connection info: 
    database product name=MySQL
    database version=5.1.73-1
    database major version=5
    database minor version=1
    jdbc driver name=MySQL Connector Java
    jdbc driver version=mysql-connector-java-5.1.38 ( Revision: fe541c166cec739c74cc727c5da96c1028b4834a )
    jdbc driver major version=5
    jdbc driver minor version=1
```

EDIT: Here is the DDL for the desk table :

```
CREATE TABLE desk
(
    type VARCHAR(31) NOT NULL,
    id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    creation_date DATETIME NOT NULL,
    creation_user VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    update_date DATETIME NOT NULL,
    update_user VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    version BIGINT NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    location_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
    user_id BIGINT,
    CONSTRAINT fk_desk_to_location FOREIGN KEY (location_id) REFERENCES location (id),
    CONSTRAINT fk_desk_to_user FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES tango_user (id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX location_id ON desk (name);
CREATE INDEX idx_desk_location_id ON desk (location_id);
CREATE INDEX idx_desk_user_id ON desk (user_id);
```

EDIT2 : I ran the same program against a SQL Server database that has the same structure as the MySQL one (it is used for the same app), and it works perfectly fine. The issue seems to be related specifically to MySQL.

Comment: What's the DDL of the table `desk`?

Comment: @Boris: I'll add it to the question tomorrow, not@work right now.

Comment: @Boris : I added the table's DDL